How to filter Not Red Cells?
The following code can filter Red Cells successfully.
Sub Macro1()
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:E500").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 0, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
End Sub

I am looking for vba code which can filter Not Red Cells.
Lets say the color of A2 cell is blue.
Lets say the color of A3 cell is green.
Lets say the color of A4 cell is red.
Lets say the color of A5 cell is yellow.
I want to filter A2, A3 and A5 cells.
I dont want to use for next loop if it is possible.
I mean I want to use only AutoFilter if it is possible.

The script follows the same approach as Michal's answer but uses a different method to populate the helper column.
Sub Demo()
    Dim helpRng As Range, visRng As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long, oSht As Worksheet
    Set oSht = Sheets("Sheet1")
    ' remove existing filter
    If oSht.AutoFilterMode Then oSht.AutoFilterMode = False
    lastRow = oSht.Cells(oSht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    With oSht.Range("A1:E" & lastRow)
        ' filter RED on Col A
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 0, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
        ' help col
        Set helpRng = .Columns(.Columns.Count).Offset(, 1)
        helpRng.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        On Error Resume Next
        ' get the visible cells on the help col
        Set visRng = helpRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not visRng Is Nothing Then
            oSht.AutoFilterMode = False
            helpRng.Clear
            ' fill the helper col
            visRng.Value = 1
            ' filter blank cells on the help col
            helpRng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=""
            ' hide the helper col
            helpRng.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub



I don't know of a direct way of doing it using a filter, if I'm wrong I will be happy to learn about it. You could use a helper column to do it using a filter.
Sub FilterNotRedCellsWithHelperColumn()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim redColor As Long
    Dim helperCol As Range
    Dim reds() As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    ' Set the worksheet and define the red color
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    redColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)

    ' Determine the last row in column A
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

    ' Set the range for the helper column
    Set helperCol = ws.Range("F1:F" & lastRow)

    ' Remove any existing filters
    If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ws.AutoFilterMode = False

    ' Step 1: Create the helper column to the right of the range (Column F in this case)
    ws.Range("F1").Value = "Helper"

    ' Step 2: Initialize a 1-dimensional array for the helper column
    ReDim reds(1 To lastRow - 1) ' 1D array to store the values for rows 2 to lastRow

    ' Step 3: Loop through column A and populate the array based on the color
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        If ws.Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = redColor Then
            reds(i - 1) = 1 ' Store 1 for red cells
        Else
            reds(i - 1) = 0 ' Store 0 for non-red cells
        End If
    Next i

    ' Step 4: Populate the helper column with the array values
    ws.Range("F2:F" & lastRow).Value = Application.Transpose(reds)

    ' Step 5: Apply filter based on the helper column (Field:=6 is column F)
    ws.Range("A1:F" & lastRow).AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="0" ' Show only non-red cells

    ' Optional: Hide the helper column
    helperCol.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End Sub

